# Relating to IR rays

Tags: experimental-physics, material-science, electronics, infrared-radiation, optical-materials

I am working on a project where I am putting an IR sensor similar to what we use IR module for Arduino.I just want a material that can pass the IR rays but it should be opaque to visible eyes .Like for example the material which is been used in front of T.V or other IR compatible remotes ..

Comment: Air transmits IR better than silicon. What you mean is that you want to transmit *only* IR, and block visible light.

Comment: no, i just want a material that can pass the IR rays but it should be opaque to visible eyes .Like for example the material which is been used in front of T.V or other IR compatible remotes .

Comment: related, and has an answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146451/what-common-materials-absorb-most-infrared-light

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a silicon waver or something similar (e.g. a shard of a broken solar panel), because silicon is transmissive for infrared frequencies, but partly reflects and absorbs visible frequencies of electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: Silicon reflects and  absorbs in the vis. You might edit to avoid confusion in third readers